# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am just trying to install mapBox in my project, and I'm getting this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Mapbox.framework/Mapbox
>     Referenced from: /Users/bero/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3146B791-A1A6-4EB6-86C4-2AA1232AF7CB/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/94E3842A-2B70-4411-B24D-908E30B1F5FC/myapp.app/myapp
>     Reason: image not found

What can I do? I have already followed the "README.md" file instructions, but with no results.

Comment: Try to clean `Derived Data` folder and then clear your simulator `Contents and Settings` then run it again.

Comment: did but now i get this: "Internal error. Please file a bug at bug report.apple.com and attach all crash logs from /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports." @u.gen

Answer (score -1):

you need to clear project, remove old app from simulator or device AND remove build folder

Comment: did but now i get this: "Internal error. Please file a bug at bug report.apple.com and attach all crash logs from /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports."

Comment: It doesn't help